# Scala Syntax Highlighting in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, syntax-highlighting, scala-ide

I'm using Eclipse & the Scala plugin to write scala code. The editor seems to have limited syntax highlighting options - for example I would like to change the formatting of variables (I like them blue) and method defs.

I know there are a few other highlighter plugins out there like EclipsesColorer, but they all seem to lose features of the Scala (or other langauges) Editor like auto complete and suggestions.

Is there any plugin or way I can modify the scala plugin to get finer control over Scala syntax coloring/formatting options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of this is being worked on. The [nightly build page](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html) has 'Semantic Highlighting' (making variables blue etc) marked as 'coming soon.

Also the [current roadmap](http://scala-ide.org/docs/dev/roadmap.html) may help with when a released version on the eclipse-scala ide.

(As 'coming soon' is very date dependent then 'today' is 10/March/12 )

Comment: Good to know, cant wait for this change, have been doing a lot less typing and a lot more reading of Scala code over the past few days, cant wait for these enhancements, will make life so much easier to follow... Thanks for the links!

Comment: You might want to update your answer, since this functionality has been added to the stable versions long ago (as @schimmy writes in his answer)

Answer (score 2):

The editor that comes with the Play Framework Eclipse plugin has syntax highlighting customizability: http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

You can go to Preferences -> Scala -> Syntax Coloring to set the different colors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Eclipse Color Theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/)?

Scala auto complete, etc. unaffected ;-)

A slightly tweaked Wombat theme in Scala works well for me (also: Aptana Eclipse plugin helps immensely with html/css/erb, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks like a very neat plugin but doesnt really give me what I want... When you say "slightly tweaked Wombat theme" what are the tweaks used to get it working with scala?

Comment: Any idea where these scala themes are now? the site seems to be done for the whole week :(

Comment: @kisna not sure, I've long since moved on from color themes as I find them largely useless on Linux (just install the < 100KB `xcalib` package and hot key invert entire screen from white to black, voila, a "color theme" ;-))